# Display Performance with two external 4K screens

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, 4k, 5k

Right now I am running two external 4K Displays (Dell) on a Dell XPS 15 Notebook with an UHD-Display (Geforce GT 750 M) on Ubuntu Linux. It feels a little bit slow.

**What can I expect if I switch over to a MacBook Pro Retina (15") or iMac 5k (27") with these two displays?**

For example - will it be possible to watch three YouTube 4K videos (each on every screen) in full screen mode without lagging?

Comment: With or without the discrete video card on the MacBook?

Comment: Of course with. I need a configuration that works smoothly. As you can see in the text I already have a discrete card and it lags in 1UHD internal screen and  two 4k external Screens (Dell 9550 GeForce GT750M i7QM, 16GB RAM, SSD)

Answer (score 1):

So now I have the 2017 MacBook Pro 15" with AMD Radeon RP560. It works with 2 External 4K Displays. It is really slow with the internal Intel Graphics Chipset. But you can deactivate automatic Graphics switching in System Settings -> Energy Saving. Then it is really usable.

I tried first with two Belkin Adapters (http://www.belkin.com/de/p/P-F2CU038/) for USB-C to HDMI. There I had some flickering problems on the Screens. Even with High-Speed-HDMI Cables (which are said to support 4k@60Hertz by the vendor).I can use these Adapters without any Problems with 2 DELL UltraSharp U2717D Displays at WQHD Resolution.

I also have two Wesimi USB-C to MiniDisplayport adapters (https://www.amazon.de/wesimi-DisplayPort-Adapterkabel-Aluminium-ChromeBook/dp/B06W54YF2P). I did not find any Manufacturer-Website for this product. That's why only the amazon link is provided. They work really great with the supplied cables from Dell (shipped with the Displays) at 4K resolution.

So now Youtube 4K Streams run smooth. And I use this Setup for my daily Work as Web-Developer. I haven't tried to use this setup for Gaming.